# How can I use conda to install pydotplus

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda, pydot

I execute the code following on my machine( Win10, python 2.7, Anaconda&Spyder) and meet `ImportError: No module named pydotplus` .

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot
G = nx.DiGraph([(1,2),(2,3),(3,2)])
write_dot(G,'file.dot')
```

It clearly that I should install `pydotplus` package. I try to `conda install pydotplus` directly but says `Error:  Package missing in current win-64 channels`. Then, I [google it](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydotplus) but find there is no information about how to install it on conda. By the way, I have install `pydot` on conda before.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Using `conda install` command below worked for me (globally installed):

`conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus`

- Using Anaconda environments (per environment instance) you can install `pydotplus` using `pip`:

`pip install pydotplus`

I would personally recommend using the Anaconda environments to install your packages for a given solution as its a more modular and cleaner way of building solutions with Anaconda.

Installing via Anaconda environments referenced from answer on `Quora`, see:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-Python-packages-in-Anaconda

Answer (score 7):

I tried `conda install pydotplus`, but it failed.

Then tried `python -m pip install pydotplus` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
pip install pydotplus
```

if it isn't part of the conda universe.

Answer (score 1):

Open Anaconda prompt:

```
pip install pydotplus
```