# NameError: name 'pydotplus' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pydotplus

I am using Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook and got the following error:

```
NameError: name 'pydotplus' is not defined
```

when running the following code for a python3 machine learning decision-tree:

```
import pandas
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as pltimg

df = pandas.read_csv("shows.csv")

d = {'UK': 0, 'USA': 1, 'N': 2}
df['Nationality'] = df['Nationality'].map(d)
d = {'YES': 1, 'NO': 0}
df['Go'] = df['Go'].map(d)

features = ['Age', 'Experience', 'Rank', 'Nationality']

X = df[features]
y = df['Go']

dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree = dtree.fit(X, y)
data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=None, feature_names=features)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(data)
graph.write_png('mydecisiontree.png')

img=pltimg.imread('mydecisiontree.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979421/how-can-i-use-conda-to-install-pydotplus

Comment: Documentation https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pydotplus

Comment: You were able to `import pydotplus` but then a `NameError` was raised when you tried using it? That doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I was able to resolve my problem in Anaconda but then I went to kaggle and couldn't make it work there. I changed to implementation to import graphiz instead and no longer sing pydotplus at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried importing the specific method you need from pydotplus instead?

Like: `from pydotplus import graph_from_dot_data` since you're only using that one method from the module.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the solution provided in the chosen answer:

```
import pydotplus # <----------------------- LOOK HERE
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree = dtree.fit(X, y)
data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=None, feature_names=features)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(data) # <-------- LOOK HERE
graph.write_png('mydecisiontree.png')

img=pltimg.imread('mydecisiontree.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

I was able to resolve my problem in Anaconda but then I went to kaggle and couldn't make it work there. I changed to implementation to import graphiz instead and no longer sing pydotplus at all.

```
import graphviz
dtree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 1,max_depth = 5,min_samples_split=2)
dtree = dtree.fit(X, y)
data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree,feature_names=features,out_file=None)
graph = graphviz.Source(data)
graph
```